# CallKit: Launch app when screen is locked

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I have implemented callkit to receive the VoIP notification.
On accept the call I am managing calls through another third party ForzenMountain which has my custom screen to show the status of calls.

1) When screen is not locked:  Call comes then it shows two button. On accept it goes into the app itself and I can manage all.

**Problem:**

2) When screen is locked: It show another transition which has multiple option like (speaker/keypad/mute/addcall) rather than to go into app.
I need to land on my app even my device is locked (if passcode enable then ask to enter it) so that I can manage FM and my custom calls screen.

Comment: Got any work around ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to go directly into your app if the phone is locked. The system will only display the native CallKit UI and from there you can tap on the bottom right button to go into your app.